# Sql Query error while using group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this: https://d1sz9tkli0lfjq.cloudfront.net/items/3w0v1Q111H0y0A093A31/Screenshot-2019-06-22T07%3A15%3A28.564Z.png

I have to query data in such a way that output will be like this: https://d1sz9tkli0lfjq.cloudfront.net/items/0P0B3K1W430h131K451F/Screenshot-2019-06-22T07%3A15%3A55.665Z.png

SQL Query Error:

> 1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and
>   contains nonaggregated column 'wp-local.visits.id' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I tried multiple queries to get such output.

```
SELECT *
FROM `rrp_visits`
WHERE `step_id` IN ( 235, 243, 247 )  
GROUP BY `rrp_visits`.`step_id` ASC
```

https://d1sz9tkli0lfjq.cloudfront.net/items/0P0B3K1W430h131K451F/Screenshot-2019-06-22T07%3A15%3A55.665Z.png

Comment: you need to use an aggregate function on every column that is not used in `group by` clause.

Comment: `ASC` belongs to `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `*` (i.e. all columns) with `GROUP BY` clause is not a good idea. Here you need to select only relevant columns only and also need to add them into `GROUP BY` clause. Also as jarlh suggested, `ASC` is used with `ORDER BY` clause.

To achieve what your expected output, use `CASE` inside `COUNT()` for this:

```
 SELECT Step_Id, COUNT(Step_Id) AS TotalVisit
 ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Visit_type = 'New' THEN Step_id ELSE NULL END) AS UniqueVisit
 FROM rrp_visits 
 WHERE step_id IN ( 235, 243, 247 )
 GROUP BY rrp_visits.step_id
```

Output:

```
| Step_Id | TotalVisit | UniqueVisit |
|---------|------------|-------------|
|     235 |          3 |           1 |
|     243 |          4 |           2 |
|     247 |          2 |           1 |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/464002/2)

Checkout [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) clause in MySQL reference manual for detailed explanation.